# Retrofit & RxJava running on JDK 7

Tags: java, api, retrofit2, rx-java, java-7

i'm working on API using java i'm using Retrofit2 and RxJava, first i program it for JDK 8 and now i have to change it to JDK 7, when it runs it keeps throwing this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: retrofit2/CallAdapter$Factory : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at networking.client.RetrofitClient.newInstance(RetrofitClient.java:14)
at tetimer.TeCampChecker.<init>(TeCampChecker.java:19)
at tetimer.TeServerTimer.scheduleTime(TeServerTimer.java:26)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

i think because RxJava adapter is using JDK 8 and converter factories i'm using, this is my code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getBaseUrl())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(TikXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

----------------------**GRADLE**--------------

```
def tikVersion = "0.8.13"
def retrofitVersion = "2.9.0"

compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofitVersion}"
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'

compileOnly("com.tickaroo.tikxml:annotation:${tikVersion}")
compile "com.tickaroo.tikxml:core:${tikVersion}"
compile "com.tickaroo.tikxml:retrofit-converter:${tikVersion}"

annotationProcessor "com.tickaroo.tikxml:auto-value-tikxml:${tikVersion}"
annotationProcessor "com.tickaroo.tikxml:processor:${tikVersion}"

compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
```

can anyone tell me what is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of Java version mismatch. Referring to the [WikipediaJava class file:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)

Java SE 10 = 54

Java SE 9 = 53

**Java SE 8 = 52**

Java SE 7 = 51

Java SE 6.0 = 50

because during compile time you are using a higher JDK and a lower JDK during runtime.

Comment: yap, i know the RxJava retrofit adapter, TikXmlConverterFactory and GsonConverterFactory uses java 8.